# Linq relations between two objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have classes:

```
class Player {
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public PlayerJob Job {get; private set;}
}

class Village {
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public int PlayerId {get; private set;}
    public int Name {get; private set;}

}
```

And having `List<Player> players` and `List<Village> villages` I would like to return `List` of `Villages` where `Village.PlayerId = Player.Id` and `Player.Job` is not null. I would like to do it using LINQ. Do you have any tips for me how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? It should be as simple as using a `Where` clause.

Comment: Answer to your question is on the same site you are on right now: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries#t=201702231147161832414

Answer (score 0):

Use `Join` and `Where`

```
var villageQuery = from v in villages 
                   join p in players
                   on v.PlayerId equals p.Id
                   where p.Job != null 
                   select v;
List<Village> villageWithPlayerJobList = villageQuery.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by joining the two lists together:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
List<Village> villages= new List<Village>();

var result = from p in players
             join v in villages on p.Id equals v.PlayerId
             where p.Job != null
             select v;
```

Comment: I would like to get list of villages

Comment: Just exchange _select p;_ with _select v;_ and you're good to go. I've updated the answer to reflect this. Although @Tim posted a similar, and correct, answer before I did.